# Random System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Operation canceled

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcpclient

I have a .net 7.0 TCP server which listens for a couple of ports and waits for clients.
I als just have introduced Sentry to it, so that crash reports will be available for me when they happen.

The TCP server works fine functionally, but it is spamming my Sentry server with this error:

`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Operation canceled`

There is no useful stack trace. You can check the Sentry issue here:

```json
{"event_id":"c8284f3c82174af6ab8703f02fe67c0d","project":8,"release":"3.8.0","dist":null,"platform":"csharp","message":"","datetime":"2023-06-07T08:20:17+00:00","tags":[["environment","staging"],["handled","yes"],["level","error"],["mechanism","chained"],["os.name","Linux"],["runtime",".NET 7.0.5"],["runtime.name",".NET"],["release","3.8.0"]],"_metrics":{"bytes.ingested.event":9952,"bytes.stored.event":16119},"contexts":{"Current Culture":{"calendar":"GregorianCalendar","display_name":"Invariant Language (Invariant Country)","type":"Current Culture"},"Dynamic Code":{"Compiled":true,"Supported":true,"type":"Dynamic Code"},"Memory Info":{"allocated_bytes":145113248,"compacted":false,"concurrent":true,"finalization_pending_count":49945,"fragmented_bytes":84211000,"heap_size_bytes":109155544,"high_memory_load_threshold_bytes":6552502272,"index":2,"memory_load_bytes":2766612070,"pause_durations":[1.126,11.1],"promoted_bytes":13046872,"total_available_memory_bytes":7280558080,"total_committed_bytes":109453312,"type":"Memory Info"},"ThreadPool Info":{"available_completion_port_threads":1000,"available_worker_threads":32766,"max_completion_port_threads":1000,"max_worker_threads":32767,"min_completion_port_threads":1,"min_worker_threads":2,"type":"ThreadPool Info"},"app":{"app_start_time":"2023-06-07T07:02:58.71+00:00","type":"app"},"device":{"boot_time":"2023-06-06T06:41:56.3975161+00:00","timezone":"Etc/UTC","timezone_display_name":"(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time","type":"device"},"os":{"name":"Linux","kernel_version":"5.15.0","raw_description":"Linux 5.15.0-1034-azure #41-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 10 19:59:45 UTC 2023","type":"os"},"runtime":{"name":".NET","version":"7.0.5","raw_description":".NET 7.0.5","identifier":"debian.11-x64","type":"runtime"}},"culprit":"Socket.Tasks.cs in void AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)","debug_meta":{"images":[{"code_id":"ff661641b33400","code_file":"/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.5/System.Private.CoreLib.dll","debug_id":"ae89c2de-f7c1-bc09-b951-47bf5cc8d568-21a12b8a","debug_file":"/__w/1/s/artifacts/obj/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/x64/Release/System.Private.CoreLib.pdb","debug_checksum":"SHA256:dec289aec1f709bcb95147bf5cc8d5688a2ba121903310f55ee88850ad2237c9","image_addr":"0x0","image_size":0,"candidates":[{"debug":{"status":"ok"},"download":{"features":{"has_debug_info":true,"has_sources":true,"has_symbols":false,"has_unwind_info":false},"status":"ok"},"source":"sentry:microsoft","source_name":"Microsoft"},{"download":{"details":"download failed: operation timed out","status":"error"},"source":"sentry:nuget","source_name":"NuGet.org"},{"download":{"status":"notfound"},"source":"sentry:project","source_name":"Sentry"}],"debug_status":"found","features":{"has_debug_info":true,"has_sources":true,"has_symbols":false,"has_unwind_info":false},"type":"pe_dotnet"},{"code_id":"ca64234ae3000","code_file":"/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.5/System.Net.Sockets.dll","debug_id":"ae740bfb-157c-f139-b8d6-eebdaa1e0ef3-4bb01919","debug_file":"/__w/1/s/artifacts/obj/System.Net.Sockets/Release/net7.0-unix/System.Net.Sockets.pdb","debug_checksum":"SHA256:fb0b74ae7c1539f1b8d6eebdaa1e0ef31919b04bb4880619f0a6a8af6932477f","image_addr":"0x0","candidates":[{"debug":{"status":"ok"},"download":{"features":{"has_debug_info":true,"has_sources":true,"has_symbols":false,"has_unwind_info":false},"status":"ok"},"source":"sentry:microsoft","source_name":"Microsoft"},{"download":{"details":"download failed: operation timed out","status":"error"},"source":"sentry:nuget","source_name":"NuGet.org"},{"download":{"status":"notfound"},"source":"sentry:project","source_name":"Sentry"}],"debug_status":"found","features":{"has_debug_info":true,"has_sources":true,"has_symbols":false,"has_unwind_info":false},"type":"pe_dotnet"}]},"environment":"staging","exception":{"values":[{"type":"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException","value":"Operation canceled","module":"System.Net.Primitives, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","stacktrace":{"frames":[{"function":"static ValueTaskSourceAsTask()+(object state) => { }","package":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","filename":"ValueTask.cs","abs_path":"/_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs","lineno":649,"in_app":false,"data":{"symbolicator_status":"symbolicated"},"instruction_addr":"0x30","addr_mode":"rel:0","function_id":"0x395f","source_link":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/8042d61b17540e49e53569e3728d2faa1c596583/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs"},{"function":"void AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)","package":"System.Net.Sockets, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","filename":"Socket.Tasks.cs","abs_path":"/_/src/libraries/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.Tasks.cs","lineno":1451,"in_app":false,"data":{"symbolicator_status":"symbolicated"},"instruction_addr":"0x17","addr_mode":"rel:1","function_id":"0x2f6","source_link":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/8042d61b17540e49e53569e3728d2faa1c596583/src/libraries/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.Tasks.cs"}]},"raw_stacktrace":{"frames":[{"function":"static ValueTaskSourceAsTask()+(object state) => { }","package":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","in_app":false,"instruction_addr":"0x30","addr_mode":"rel:0","function_id":"0x395f"},{"function":"void AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)","package":"System.Net.Sockets, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","in_app":false,"instruction_addr":"0x17","addr_mode":"rel:1","function_id":"0x2f6"}]},"thread_id":2,"mechanism":{"type":"chained","handled":true,"source":"InnerExceptions[0]","exception_id":1,"parent_id":0}},{"type":"System.AggregateException","value":"A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.","module":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","thread_id":2,"mechanism":{"type":"UnobservedTaskException","description":"This exception was thrown from a task that was unobserved, such as from an async void method, or a Task.Run that was not awaited. This exception was unhandled, but likely did not crash the application.","handled":false,"is_exception_group":true,"exception_id":0}}]},"fingerprint":["{{ default }}"],"grouping_config":{"enhancements":"eJybzDRxY3J-bm5-npWRgaGlroGxrpHxBABcYgcZ","id":"newstyle:2019-10-29"},"hashes":["dd15ca484678e4f6398e85a35e50b454"],"key_id":"8","level":"error","location":"TaskExceptionHolder.cs","logger":"","metadata":{"display_title_with_tree_label":false,"filename":"TaskExceptionHolder.cs","function":"void TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()","type":"System.AggregateException","value":"A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread."},"modules":{"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights":"2.21.0.429","Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore":"2.21.0.429","Microsoft.AspNetCore":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Metadata":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Features":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Http":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Logging":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Options":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers":"7.0.0.0","Microsoft.Win32.Primitives":"7.0.0.0","Newtonsoft.Json":"13.0.0.0","RabbitMQ.Client":"6.0.0.0","Sentry":"3.33.0.0","Sentry.AspNetCore":"3.33.0.0","Sentry.Extensions.Logging":"3.33.0.0","System.Buffers":"7.0.0.0","System.Collections":"7.0.0.0","System.Collections.Concurrent":"7.0.0.0","System.Collections.Immutable":"7.0.0.0","System.Collections.NonGeneric":"7.0.0.0","System.ComponentModel":"7.0.0.0","System.ComponentModel.Annotations":"7.0.0.0","System.ComponentModel.Primitives":"7.0.0.0","System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter":"7.0.0.0","System.Console":"7.0.0.0","System.Data.Common":"7.0.0.0","System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource":"7.0.0.0","System.Diagnostics.Process":"7.0.0.0","System.Diagnostics.StackTrace":"7.0.0.0","System.Diagnostics.TraceSource":"7.0.0.0","System.Diagnostics.Tracing":"7.0.0.0","System.Formats.Asn1":"7.0.0.0","System.IO.Compression":"7.0.0.0","System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher":"7.0.0.0","System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles":"7.0.0.0","System.IO.Pipelines":"7.0.0.0","System.Linq":"7.0.0.0","System.Linq.Expressions":"7.0.0.0","System.Memory":"7.0.0.0","System.Net.Http":"7.0.0.0","System.Net.NameResolution":"7.0.0.0","System.Net.Primitives":"7.0.0.0","System.Net.Quic":"7.0.0.0","System.Net.Security":"7.0.0.0","System.Net.Sockets":"7.0.0.0","System.Net.WebSockets":"7.0.0.0","System.Numerics.Vectors":"7.0.0.0","System.ObjectModel":"7.0.0.0","System.Private.CoreLib":"7.0.0.0","System.Private.Uri":"7.0.0.0","System.Private.Xml":"7.0.0.0","System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration":"7.0.0.0","System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight":"7.0.0.0","System.Reflection.Metadata":"7.0.0.0","System.Reflection.Primitives":"7.0.0.0","System.Runtime":"7.0.0.0","System.Runtime.InteropServices":"7.0.0.0","System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation":"7.0.0.0","System.Runtime.Intrinsics":"7.0.0.0","System.Runtime.Loader":"7.0.0.0","System.Runtime.Numerics":"7.0.0.0","System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters":"7.0.0.0","System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives":"7.0.0.0","System.Security.Claims":"7.0.0.0","System.Security.Cryptography":"7.0.0.0","System.Text.Encoding.Extensions":"7.0.0.0","System.Text.Encodings.Web":"7.0.0.0","System.Text.Json":"7.0.0.0","System.Text.RegularExpressions":"7.0.0.0","System.Threading":"7.0.0.0","System.Threading.Channels":"7.0.0.0","System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions":"7.0.0.0","System.Threading.Thread":"7.0.0.0","System.Threading.ThreadPool":"7.0.0.0","System.Web.HttpUtility":"7.0.0.0","System.Xml.ReaderWriter":"7.0.0.0","TcpServer":"3.8.0.0","netstandard":"2.1.0.0"},"nodestore_insert":1686126023.807124,"received":1686126017.390753,"sdk":{"name":"sentry.dotnet","version":"3.33.0","packages":[{"name":"nuget:sentry.dotnet","version":"3.33.0"}]},"threads":{"values":[{"id":2,"stacktrace":{"frames":[{"function":"void TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()","package":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","filename":"TaskExceptionHolder.cs","abs_path":"/_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskExceptionHolder.cs","lineno":68,"in_app":false,"data":{"symbolicator_status":"symbolicated"},"instruction_addr":"0x2e","addr_mode":"rel:0","function_id":"0x3853","source_link":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/8042d61b17540e49e53569e3728d2faa1c596583/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskExceptionHolder.cs"}]},"raw_stacktrace":{"frames":[{"function":"void TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()","package":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","in_app":false,"instruction_addr":"0x2e","addr_mode":"rel:0","function_id":"0x3853"}]},"crashed":false,"current":true}]},"timestamp":1686126017.204606,"title":"System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception ...","type":"error","version":"7"}
```

or formatted here: https://pastebin.com/G7t6Q604

I have built loads of debugging try-catch clauses, and have put `ContinueWith` after every  `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

I ran out of ideas on how to analyse this, so I was hoping someone here has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

View your trace in jsonbeautifier and you will see this one:

```
"value": "A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. 
    As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread."
```

You can try to wrap with try/catch all suspected code areas and capture OperationCancelledException, then check out your logs again.
I would try this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are completely right, but as I said, I already put try-catch clauses and ContinueWith's around everything suspicious.